# A Special case of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm sitting with a special case of GBM where $B(t)$ is Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I want to find the expected value of $A(t)$, where $A(t)$ is given by
$$A(t)=exp(B(t))B(t)+C$$
and C is a constant. Has anyone worked with such a model before?

I'm thinking that
$$E[A(t)]=E[B(t) \exp(\mu t)]+C=\mu t\exp(\mu t)+C$$
is the answer to the expected value (not 100% sure), but how do I determine the variance of $A(t)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B(t)$ has a normal distribution with mean $\mu t$ and variance $\sigma^2 t$, you know that its density function is $$p_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 t}} e^{-(x-\mu t)^2/2\sigma^2 t}.$$
So you can find the expected value of any function $f(B(t))$ by computing the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) p_t(x)\,dx$.  For $E[A(t)]$, you'll compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^x x + C) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 t}} e^{-(x-\mu t)^2/2\sigma^2 t}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 t}} x e^{x -(x-\mu t)^2/2\sigma^2t}\,dx + C.$$
This should be easily computed by a change of variables.  Maple says we get
$$e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t/2} (\sigma^2 t + \mu t).
$$
The variance should be computable by a similar technique; I think there may be an integration by parts needed as well.

Comment: Thanks, I see
p_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 t}} e^{-(x-\mu t)^2/2\sigma^2 t} right?

Comment: @Jimmy: Yes, fixed.